# text not append after image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**problem is text not append after image**

```
 <?php '<p>Name : <span id="txt_name'.$k.'">'.$change->name.'</span>';?> 
<img id="copyButton" class="img-1" 
 onClick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('txt_name<?PHP echo $k; ?>'));" 
 src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-
  1/16/copy-icon.png" title="Click here to copy the text into clipboard."> </p>
```

i want to append text when user click on image than meg show on the right side of image text copied.

```
    $("img").click(function() {
     var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
        // $(".myClass").append("<div>Copied</div>");
          // $(this).after("copied");
  });
$(".myClass").append("<div>Copied</div>");
```

i have 3 images with different class name

Comment: damn that's quite a mess... can you strip out the php and post a well-marked-up piece of html and javascript?

Comment: Image elements do not have children, so trying to append other elements to them makes no sense in the first place. You want to use `after`, `insertAfter` or sth. like that instead in such a situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/):-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function() {
      $("<div>Copied</div>").insertAfter($(this));
    });
});
```

Or use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/):-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function() {
      $(this).after("<div>Copied</div>");
    });
});
```

Note:- Make sure that jQuery library added before this script code